# Haskell - why getSymbolicLinkTarget is not in scope?

Tags: haskell

I get this error:

```
/home/jacek/hasktemp/src/Main.hs:40:31: error:
    Variable not in scope: getSymbolicLinkTarget :: [Char] -> IO a0
   |
40 |                 symlTarget <- getSymbolicLinkTarget emacsdf
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

when I try to find the target of a symlink.

The gist of my code is here:
https://gist.github.com/bigos/9da53d11c53fe642bfe90444be76cb7c

and my imports have

```
import System.Directory
```

The documentation
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.3.1/docs/System-Directory.html#g:6
has getSymbolicLinkTarget, yet I get the error. what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you installed the *correct* package (same name, same version)? Unfortunately every now and then *different* packages offer the *same module names* (but frequently with *different* functions).

Comment: Here `directory` and `system-fileio` both have a `System.Directory` module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getSymbolicLinkTarget`'s documentation says, in part:

> Since: directory-1.3.1.0

You probably have an older version of the directory package than that. Consider adding a constraint like `directory>=1.3.1` to your cabal file.